# how to declare input tag value to php variable using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html

this is my function

```
function selectdata($conn)
{

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `schb1` WHERE ID= '2019_March_W1_friday_1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
       echo "<script>".$ff."=document.getElementById('inputyear').value;</script>";
       echo "<script>document.getElementById('demo').value='".$ff."';</script>";  
   }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

}
```

i want to declare **input tag value** to **php variable** and i tried  this,

```
echo "<script>".$ff."=document.getElementById('inputyear').value;</script>";
```

i don't want to use get or post method i want to do this using **document.getElementById**

if anybody can give me a solution to this i would me much grateful thank you!

Comment: Are you pre-defined variable $ff >

Comment: do you want to assign the value of input to $ff php variable?

Comment: give your html code also

Comment: @Hasee Amarathunga  it didnt work

Comment: <input type="text" name="year"  id="inputyear" onchange="year_and_month_change()"
                  style="border: none; text-align: center; width: 100px;"
                  value="<?php echo date("Y");?>"/>                                                                                        this is the input tag @Zeeshan Ahmad Khalil

Comment: yes @Zeeshan Ahmad Khalil

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP runs on the server before sending its output to the client, you can't use document.getElementById to set the value of a php variable. There is no document and no elements with values.